# Creating choice directed dialogue but says choices are out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Inky in unity to create choice driven dialogue; I have set it up so that you drag and drop the choices in the Dialogue manager object. I have set the first choices int to 0 and the 2nd choices int to 1.

My code will not allow me to select and run the Inky code that in associates with the option and throws an error saying the object is out of range

Inky Dialogue:

```
-> main
== main ==
Hello there! My family and I are getting ready to set some traps in the nearby stream.
Would you like to hear the story?
    +[Yes]
        -> chosen("Yes")
    +[No]
        -> chosen("No")

== chosen(Yes) ==
Great news I'll tell you the story!
->DONE

==chosen1(No)==
Okay comback when you want to hear it.
->END
```

Here is the code for the Dialogue Manager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using Ink.Runtime;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DIalogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    [Header("Dialogue UI")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject dialoguePanel;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI dialogueText;

    [Header("Choices UI")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] choices;
    private TextMeshProUGUI[] choicesText;

    private Story currentStory;

    public bool dialogueIsPlaying {get; private set; }

    private static DIalogueManager instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Found more than one dialogue manager in this scene");

        }
        instance = this;

    }

    public static DIalogueManager GetInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        dialogueIsPlaying = false;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);

        //get all of the choices text
        choicesText = new TextMeshProUGUI[choices.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (GameObject choice in choices)
        {
            choicesText[index] = choice.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //return right away id the dialogue is not playing
        if (!dialogueIsPlaying)
        {
            return;
        }

        //handle continuing to the next line in the dialogue when submit is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            ContinueStory();
        }
    }

    public void EnterDialogueMode(TextAsset inkJSON)
    {
        currentStory = new Story(inkJSON.text);
        dialogueIsPlaying = true;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(true);

       ContinueStory();

    }

    private void ExitDialogueMode()
    {
        dialogueIsPlaying = false;
        dialoguePanel.SetActive(false);
        dialogueText.text = "";
    }

    private void ContinueStory()
    {
        if (currentStory.canContinue)
        {
            //set text for the current dialogue line
            dialogueText.text = currentStory.Continue();

            //display choices
            DisplayChoices();
        }
        else
        {
            ExitDialogueMode();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayChoices()
    {
        List<Choice> currentChoices = currentStory.currentChoices;

        //Defensive check to make sure that the UI can suppor teh number of choices
        if (currentChoices.Count > choices.Length)
        {
            Debug.LogError("More choices were given then the UI can support. NUmber of choices given: " +currentChoices.Count);
        }

        int index = 0;
        //enable and initialise choices 
        foreach(Choice choice in currentChoices)
        {
            choices[index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
            choicesText[index].text = choice.text;
            index++;
        }
        //go through the remaining chouces that are supported by the UI and make sure they are hidden
        for (int i = index; i < choices.Length; i++)
        {
            choices[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        StartCoroutine(SelectFirstChoice());
    }

    private IEnumerator SelectFirstChoice()
    {
        //event systems requires for it to be cleared first, then wait
        //at least one frame before we set the current selected object.
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(choices[0].gameObject);
    }

    public void MakeChoice(int choiceIndex)
    {
        currentStory.ChooseChoiceIndex(choiceIndex);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the dialogue trigger:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DialogueTrigger1 : MonoBehaviour
{
   //VIsual Cue SHow up when player in bounds of box collider
   [Header("VisualCue")]
   [SerializeField] private GameObject visualCue;

   [Header("Ink JSON")]
   [SerializeField] private TextAsset inkJSON;

   //Keeps track if the player is in range
   public bool playerInRange;

   private void Awake()
   {
        playerInRange = false;
        visualCue.SetActive(false);
   }

    //Shows the visual cue if player is in range
   void Update()
   {
        if (playerInRange && !DIalogueManager.GetInstance().dialogueIsPlaying)
        {
            visualCue.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerInRange == true)
            {
                DIalogueManager.GetInstance().EnterDialogueMode(inkJSON);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            visualCue.SetActive(false);
        }
   }

    //Detects colliders
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
   {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
   }

   private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider)
   {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think this line has issue `for (int i = index`, it should be `for (int i = 0`

Comment: In general I wouldn't mix `foreach` and index based access .. rather convert those into `for` loops which is way better to read and maintain (imho)

Comment: I tried the for(int i = 0), but it just doesn't show any of the choices, I am not sure how to convert the foreach to for loops sorry, I'm very new to C#